# Typescript UseContext React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and react and am getting this error, on default card

I am trying to setup use context and will use it with use state or use reducer but I am having trouble wrapping my head around initial setup for this

```
Error:
Argument of type '{ cartitem: { id: number; name: string; description: string; price: string; }; addCart: () => void; removeCart: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CartContextType'.
  Types of property 'cartitem' are incompatible.
    Type '{ id: number; name: string; description: string; price: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ICart[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2345)



import React, { createContext } from 'react';
export interface ICart {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: string;
  }

export type CartContextType = {
    cartitem: ICart[];
    addCart: (cart: ICart, totalAmount:number) => void;
    removeCart: (id: number) => void;
  };

  const defalutCart={cartitem:{
    id: 0,
    name: 'string',
    description: 'string',
    price: 'string'},
    addCart: () => {},
    removeCart: () => { }
  }

export const CartContext = createContext<CartContextType | null>(defalutCart);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `defalutCart` needs the property `cartitem` to be an array. With the correct spelling and changes, here is your updated code:

```
const defaultCart = {
  cartitem: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "string",
      description: "string",
      price: "string",
    },
  ],
  addCart: () => {},
  removeCart: () => {},
};
```

Do you see how the object is now wrapped in an array? Please mark this as correct if it solves your problem.